# Number of elements of order 2 in $ S_6$

Tags: group-theory

Find number of Elements of order 2 in $ S_6$.

My attempt:

It is clear that permutations would be of form:

1. (a b)
2. (a b)(c d)
3. (a b)(c d)(e f)

Option 1. Will have $\frac{6!}{2.4!}$ permutations

Option 2. Will have $\frac{ \frac{6!}{2.4!} . \frac{4!}{2.2!}}{2}$

Option 3. Will have $\frac{ \frac{6!}{2.4!} . \frac{4!}{2.2!} . \frac{2!}{2}}{3}$

So adding them total is 90. But answer in book is 75. What is going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the third case, there are $3!$ possible orderings of the three transpositions, so you should be dividing the quantity in the numerator by $3!$, not $3$.

In fact, you can save some computation by observing the following: Let $n_k$ be the number of distinct products of $k$ transpositions.

First, there is a bijective correspondence
$$\{(ab)(cd)(ef)\} \leftrightarrow \{(cd)(ef), (ab)(ef), (ab)(cd)\}$$
given by taking a product of three transpositions, and separately pulling out each of the three transpositions. Thus, $n_2 = 3 n_3$.

Likewise, there is a bijective correspondence
$$\{(ab)\} \leftrightarrow \{(cd)(ef), (ce)(df), (cf)(de)\}$$
given by taking a transposition $\lambda$ and writing out the three products of the transpositions built out of the four elements not in $\lambda$. So, again, $n_2 = 3 n_1$ and thus $n_1$ = $n_3$.

So, the total number of elements of order $2$ is
$$n_1 + n_2 + n_3 = n_1 + 3 n_1 + n_1 = 5 n_1,$$ but $n_1 = 15$, so the total number of elements is $$5 (15) = 75$$ as desired.

Comment: Ok so if there is product of n cycles of same length, then do we divide by n!?

Comment: Yes, because the order doesn't matter, and there are $n!$ ways to order $n$ objects.

Comment: If you don't divide by the number of orderings of the cycles of same length, you would count for example both permutations $(1 \ 2)(3 \ 4)$ and $(3 \ 4)(1 \ 2)$, even though they are representations of the same permutation (disjoint cycles commute).